# How to generate a variable for matched observations

Tags: regression, stata, matching, sample

I'm using Stata to analyze some clinic data. In my dataset, I want to match 5000 treated observations each with more than 1 untreated observation. And I want to generate a dummy variable to indicate if the observation is matched or not - so that I can drop unmatched observations and only run regression using matched ones.

Comment: Can you say more about how you want to match the observations? That can be done in many different ways.

Comment: I agree with @TheIceBear that we need to know more about how you want to implement your matching approach to be able to answer. But in case it's helpful, I have found Ben Jann's user-written `kmatch`, available from SSC, to be an excellent package for implementing various matching routines, and it may suffice for your purposes.